# django.contrib.admin like application for cherrypy

Tags: python, django, cherrypy

Is there a django.contrib.admin like app / module for cherrypy? 
I really like the simplicity of cherrypy, but it would be nice, to have the user authentication and password management type things taken care of... 
Or is it possible to run a cherrypy application behind the django admin app ?

Answer (score 3):

Django admin is much more, but is bound to Models. Without them, You will not gain much and as there is no such concept in CherryPy, I doubt there is similar application.

However, Django admin is phpmyadmin for masses exploited. Don't be constrained by it and create much more usable admin apps, leveraging CherryPy simplicity ^_^

Answer (score 2):

There is no database backend in CherryPy so there cannot be any Admin-interface for it.

But you can use any database backend with CherryPy.

For example you could use [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/). It has an admin interface called [Futon](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/tour.html#welcome). Futon is of course somewhat low level compared to Django Admin/Models.